# excel listObject issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have inherited a spreadsheet full of VBA I know next to nothing about.

When the data is refreshed, the spreadsheet re-formats itself via the VBA.  I had to change some tab names and table names and now when the auto reformat kicks in it gives an error as it is looking for the old table name.

Sorry if this s a bad explanation/terminology, I really never get involved with VBA usually!

So the error I get is

> Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

debug takes me to this line

```
For Each rptTable In sID.ListObjects
    rptTable.TableStyle = teamName   <--- this is the highlighted line in debug
    oldSize = rptTable.ListRows.Count
    If oldSize < teamSize Then
```

teamName has the new value, rptTable.TableStyle has the old value.

the variables are defined as follow i believe:

```
Sub FormatSheet(sID As Worksheet)
'Clear debugWindow
Call clearDebugConsole
Application.StatusBar = "Formatting Teamsheet ... "

'Change Active Sheet to the Sheet being Formatted
Worksheets(sID.Name).Activate

Debug.Print "* Entered FormatSheet Sub"

' Set Variables
....
Dim rptTable As ListObject
```

I basically trying to work out how the `ListObject` is being populated and where the old name is being picked up from?  a global search in the excel spreadsheet doesn't pick it up

Comment: `Can you write rptTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"` to see whether it would work? Instead of the highighted line.

Comment: if you know nothing about the vba in the file that you've received, why did you risk messing it up by changing stuff? better take a new copy and go through the whole thing first and understand how it all works together before you attempt changes

Comment: I have changed the actual live one - I took a copy and am changing this.  Problem is when a boss wants something done yesterday, they just want it done!

Comment: well it goes without saying that from now on you should never work on a live version, always work on a local copy. in any case, your error suggests that `teamName` might not be in the correct format. you might have changed it to the correct value, but maybe its type is now wrong. its not possible to determine what the issue is without seeing all the relevant code. if you have shadow backup then get an earlier version of the file and start clean

Comment: form now on?  i just said i used a copy, not the live version...

Comment: you wrote "I have changed the actual live one". anyway if you have a clean copy then start from there, first read all of it to understand how it works. trust me it will be much easier to alter it afterwards

Comment: ah crap sorry, that was meant to say haven't* :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that teamname has a value that does not correspond to anything in TableStyles.

stop the code on that line and see what value variable teamname holds. There needs to be value that exists in your table styles. My guess is there is empty string. You need to assign it something like "TableStyleMedium2" etc.. You can find these names in the design ribbon -> table styles. Use the value without spaces.

Comment: Ah ok so i think the problem is someone has created custom table styles and given them their own name.  I just need to work out how to change that tabestyle custom name

Comment: Well you posted only part of the code so we cannot really say where is teamName declared and how the program use that variable. Look with ctrl-f and see where is it used and how.

Comment: no its great you pointed me into the right direction thanks.  They created custom table styles with their own names.  When i changed the "table"name in the front end it not longer matched the table style name.  the table style name never appeared in ctrl-f but i found out how to change them now.  thanks